# .htaccess url on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

I got a small problem with my .htaccess file. It does work but somehow doesn't work a 100%.
I'm looking for a way to build the website depending on the url. So for example 'example.com/en/home' would be the home page. The problem is that i can only get it to work when the url is like this: 'example.com/index/en/home'

My code in the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /htaccess/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Domain:

```
localhost/~axll/htaccess/
```

The root folder is located on a localhost(xampp for mac) under htaccess. If I understand correctly, it should append 'en/home' to the index file, so I should be able to just leave the 'index' part out in the url, am i right?

EDIT 1:
I used the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] in php and got back the following:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => php [2] => test )
```

Shouldn't the index of the array be different then NULL?

Comment: Unless your site is in a directory called htaccess, I think your `RewriteBase` should be `/`

Comment: I agree. `RewriteBase /htaccess/` - um, no

Comment: Sorry - missed that line of your description. not sure how your domain is set up but I'm still suspicious of that line.

Comment: I added the domain in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in your host configuration you set **AllowOverride None**? It will disable use of .htaccess files

Change it to AllowOverride **All** to enable

Comment: Where can I find/change that exactly?

Comment: In your apache host configuration file httpd.conf or virtual host confgs in sites-enabled or etc.

Comment: I changed and tested it. The problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I couldn't find any mistakes so i just reinstalled my localhost and it did the trick. Thanks everybody for helping!